# Emacs as a C Programming IDE Configuration?

Tags: c, emacs, ide

I use emacs as my main IDE for programming in C. I am exploring ways of configuring emacs to function more as an IDE rather than as a simple text editor. Of course I want syntax highlighting and preferably some code completion. I also want separate buffers to allow shell commands and to M-x compile. I want it to open into this multi-buffer form automatically when visiting a C source file, rather than having to launch each buffer separately. I will be using this mainly for Linux/BSD Unix development, though I also code on Mac OS X (again Unix) and Windows (Windows 7 64bit).

I explored the Emacs starter kit posted by Phil Hagelberg (technomancy), but it seems very oriented towards dynamic languages and use of git. I use emacs mainly for developing in C and use mercurial for VC. I am also a relative newbie making configuration of emacs relatively daunting for me.

I am now playing with CEDET and the Emacs Code Browser (ECB) package which is more along the lines of what I want, but is still not perfect.

Any suggestions on customizing emacs as a C programming IDE welcome.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421/using-emacs-as-an-ide) is similar

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done C but here are a few pointers.

1. Use [flymake](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake#toc1) for on the fly error analysis. I have used it for Python and C and it's really awesome.
2. Syntax highlighting is there by default in the C mode.
3. M-x compile is geared towards make so if you have a Makefile in your setup, it should work fine (the defauly flymake rules use this as well). A rule like this

```
check-syntax:
          gcc -Wall -o nul -S ${CHK_SOURCES}
```

would take care of flymake. [This](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UsingMakefileFromParentDirectory) is useful when you edit in subdirectories but want to compile fromt he top.

4. [etags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/etags.html) is useful to jump around the code. [GnuGlobal](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuGlobal) also seems to be popular.
5. Can't comment on ECB since I've never really gotten it to work completely and when I sort of did, I never found it that useful. I use [autocomplete.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) to do completions but it's not context sensitive.
6. There is no suggestion 6.
7. The inbuilt vc integration is not so hot for `git` and so I use [magit](https://github.com/nelhage/magit) instead. There should be similar options for mercurial.
8. There are some notes here on setting up your [indentation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC).
9. You should use [which function mode](http://w3.pppl.gov/info/emacs/Which_Function.html). It's saved me a lot of headache in the past.
10. The defaults for [GUD](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrandUnifiedDebugger) are pretty decent but you should take a while and familiarise yourself with them to use it's power completely.
11. I heavily use [org-capture](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) to move TBDs into my org mode buffers so that I can track them as TODO items. This is for all languages. I also use org-mode to maintain a development diary for all my projects.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Read this [excellent guide](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) on how to configure CEDET. I'd also advise you to use [cscope](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CScopeAndEmacs) and ECB alongside it. As Noufal already mentioned autocomplete and flymake are very helpful. I'd also recommend you [autopair mode](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/).

Answer (score 1):

i didn't try out [Emacs-IDE](http://emacs-ide.tuxfamily.org/) but it seems useful and may help you