# IDE which uses a textual user interface ( like ncurses)

Tags: emacs, ide, ncurses, curses, tui

are there any IDEs which run in a shell instead of a gui. As i really don't like to use a mouse (except of scrolling, everything is faster for example in firefox using shortcuts).

I really like textual user interfaces (like gdb in tui mode) and it would be nice to have an ide which is fully controlable by keyboard (i'm currently learning emacs but it isn't really designed as an ide i think).

Comment: What languages are you working with? For instance, emacs can be a very effective IDE for some platforms and not so much for others.

Comment: Most of the time i'm programming C and Python, sometimes also Ruby.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Emacs as an IDE(with some script/package and setup) (take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421/using-emacs-as-an-ide))

- Emacs + [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) + [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/): Java IDE
- Emacs + [Slime](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/): Common Lisp IDE
- Emacs + [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) + [Cedet](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/)(and [Xrefactory](http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/main.html)): C++ IDE(Alex Ott written a
  great [article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) about it)
- Emacs + [Pymacs](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/index.html) + [Ropemacs](http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropemacs.html): Python IDE

Answer (score 1):

emacs and vim can be - and are - both used as IDEs. I personally use emacs as IDE for PHP.