# Emacs as an Eclipse alternative

Tags: java, eclipse, emacs, ide

I use Eclipse for my day job, working on a enterprise java project. Here are some things I got used to working with Eclipse,

1. Most of the coding are done to interfaces and concrete classes are wired using factories or using spring dependency injection like,

   > ```
   > InterfaceName obj=ObjFactory.getImpl(args)
   > ```
   >
   > I have to look at Class hierarchy often to go to the method that is being invoked, this is very easy in Eclipse (C+T)
2. Code completion for all methods (methods in different source files and from jars).
3. Highlight errors while editing.
4. Tracing call hierarchy

I tried Emacs some time back for shell scripting on a remote machine and I found that to be very useful.
I would love to use Emacs for my java development if there are tools out there which can help me do things that I do with Eclipse. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look here if it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421/using-emacs-as-an-ide

Comment: Check out [eclim](http://eclim.org/) which provides useful Eclipse features for Emacs and VIM using Eclipse itself.

Comment: eclim seems to be a nice fit. I will give it a try when I find some time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is off-topic on [so], useful though.