# Emacs as an IDE for large C++ projects

Tags: c++, emacs, ide

I am a Emacs newbie. I have to trying to search on how to use Emacs for use with large C++ projects particularly to index code and auto-complete function names and behave Eclipse-like. I had been using Vim for some time where I used ctags to index code in my project and Vim used to try auto-completing my code using a drop down menu of options. I am trying to achieve the same with Emacs now. But, during my search, results pointed to CEDET and auto-complete and other 3rd party plugins.

I tried to use ctags with `ctags -e -R .` and etags, but with no success.

Am I missing a default way of Emacs to achieve the same behavior? Which is the best and easiest way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You may want to check out GNU global plus xgtags.el and clang based auto-complete. Semantic can make use of both as well.

Comment: Check out clang for c++ autocompletion: http://root42.blogspot.hu/2012/07/nice-c-autocomplete-configuration-for.html

Comment: I'm currently developing [`clang-tags`](https://github.com/ffevotte/clang-tags), an indexing tool based on clang.  It's still in the early stages of the development, but you might find it useable. If you do try it, I would be very glad to get some feedback on github.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use CEDET with autocomplete successfully. Basically, autocomplete is the drop-down box provider, and it takes its sources from various things, most interestingly from CEDET (but also from etags and Gnu Global, which I recommend too).

A good starting point for CEDET is http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html

Alex Ott's emacs config is there: https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs -- it's an useful resource.

Note that you'll need to grab CEDET from bzr, and install/configure autocomplete correctly. I strongly recommend el-get to install autocomplete (and some other stuff too). You'll need to set up generic projects for EDE to have autocompletion working for random C/C++ files not part of a structured EDE project.

You'll have to spend some time to configure emacs, but it pays off. The tool is amazingly productive once set up correctly.

Comment: +1 for "The tool is amazingly productive once set up correctly"

Comment: I may have to note that I don't use CEDET anymore, due to the fact that the C++ parser is not very accurate, and slow as hell. I use now the libclang based irony-mode for completion, and gtags for navigation.

Answer (score 12):

**Indexing**

You might want to use [GNU/global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) instead of ctags: it supports C++ and is in my opinion more efficient with large projects (especially since you can update the index instead of rebuilding it from scratch). And it still is a lot simpler to use that CEDET/Semantic (which is also a fantastic tool if you spend the time to set it up).

Example use:

```sh
$ cd sources
$ gtags -v         # create the index
$ cd subdirectory
$ [hack hack hack]
$ global -u        # update the index (can be called from anywhere in the project)
```

In Emacs, activate `gtags-mode` in the source code buffers to get access to the gtags commands:

- `gtags-find-tag` (<kbd>M-.</kbd>) : find the definition of the specified tag in your source files (`gtags` lets you choose between all possible definitions if there are several, or directly jumps if there is only one possibility)
- `gtags-pop-stack` (<kbd>M-*</kbd>) : return to the previous location
- `gtags-find-rtag` : find all uses of the specified tag in the source files

Below is my configuration for `gtags`, which automatically activates `gtags-mode` if an index is found:

```lisp
;; gtags-mode
(eval-after-load "gtags"
  '(progn
     (define-key gtags-mode-map (kbd "M-,") 'gtags-find-rtag)))
(defun ff/turn-on-gtags ()
  "Turn `gtags-mode' on if a global tags file has been generated.

This function asynchronously runs 'global -u' to update global
tags. When the command successfully returns, `gtags-mode' is
turned on."
  (interactive)
  (let ((process (start-process "global -u"
                                "*global output*"
                                "global" "-u"))
        (buffer  (current-buffer)))
    (set-process-sentinel
     process
     `(lambda (process event)
        (when (and (eq (process-status process) 'exit)
                   (eq (process-exit-status process) 0))
          (with-current-buffer ,buffer
            (message "Activating gtags-mode")
            (gtags-mode 1)))))))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'ff/turn-on-gtags)
```

---

**Automatic completion**

I don't know of any better tool than [`auto-complete`](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/index.html). Even if it is not included within Emacs, it is very easily installable using the packaging system (for example in the [marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/auto-complete) or [melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) repositories).

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you are looking for in an IDE. I have been using Emacs for a fairly large C++ project. Of course you need to configure emacs to work as you want it to work in a greater extent they any other IDE.

But yes CEDET is a start, even though it is not perfect.

However there is a very good auto complete mode for Emacs http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/ it is not intelisense but it should integrate with CEDET in some way to give you a farily good auto complete.

Another important feature that I often use is the function `ff-find-other-file` to easy jump from header and implementation files.

Then of course you need to roll your own bulid. CEDET has some support for projects, but I have not tested it. However Emacs integrate well with command-line build tools such as make. Errors are printed in a buffer and you can jump to the correct line easily within Emacs.

GDB is also integrates well with Emacs `M-x gdb`, then just remember the `gdb-many-windows`  command.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to watch Atila Neves lightning talk at CppCon 2015 titled [Emacs as a C++ IDE](https://youtu.be/5FQwQ0QWBTU).

For for details, see my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33721012/783510).

Answer (score 1):

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26518/sequence-of-packages-to-be-installed-to-make-emacs-an-ide-for-c-c

I use GNU Global and two popular Emacs plugins:

- company for code completion
- emacs-helm-gtags for code navigation