# How to use gtags -v to create index but skipping some subdirectories

Tags: c++, c, gnu-global

I am trying to run 'gtags -v' to build index for my large code base.
from this link:
[Emacs as an IDE for large C++ projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282233/emacs-as-an-ide-for-large-c-projects)

My question is how can I tell gtags to skip walk into some directories (not necessary top level) "e.g. 'out', '.git', 'tools'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can skip certain filetypes and directories with the `--exclude` argument.

`--exclude=*.txt,*.html`

Edit: It seems my answer works for ctags, but may not exist in gtags any more. [Please see this page for a possible solution to your problem.](http://web.archive.org/web/20140121020918/http://alexbiddle.github.io/2013/12/16/gtags-exclude-directory.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can add the file/dirs you want to exclude to your ~/.globalrc file in the `common: skip:` section.
For example:

> `common:\
>
>   :skip=HTML/,HTML.pub/,tags,TAGS,ID,y.tab.c,y.tab.h,gtags.files,cscope.files,cscope.out,cscope.po.out,cscope.in.out,SCCS/,RCS/,CVS/,CVSROOT/,{arch}/,autom4te.cache/,*.orig,*.rej,*.bak,*~,#*#,*.swp,*.tmp,*_flymake.*,*_flymake,*.o,*.a,*.so,*.lo,*.zip,*.gz,*.bz2,*.xz,*.lzh,*.Z,*.tgz,*.min.js,*min.css:`

**P.S.** If you don't have `.globalrc` in your HOME dir, you can copy it from `gtags.conf` from source code archive of `global`.

[This page may help you.](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Btags/gtags)