# how gtags exclude some specific subdirectories

Tags: emacs, directory

Gtags (GNU GLOBAL Source Code Tag System) I use in emacs default tag the root directory and its sub directories recursively. But there are some sub directories I don't want to be tagged. Could anybody give me some advises. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ~/.globalrc. answer is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703585/how-to-use-gtags-v-to-create-index-but-skipping-some-subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exploring function ggtags-create-tags, I found that there is configure file gtags.conf/.globalrc with which I solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Copy `gtags.conf` into your HOME diretory:

```
cp /usr/local/share/gtags/gtags.conf ~/.globalrc
```

Edit `~/.globalrc`, add the files to be ignored into following line:

```
common:\
:skip=HTML/,HTML.pub/,tags,TAGS,ID,y.tab.c,y.tab.h,gtags.files,cscope.files,cscope.out,cscope.po.out,cscope.in.out,SCCS/,RCS/,CVS/,CVSROOT/,{arch}/,autom4te.cache/,*.orig,*.rej,*.bak,*~,#*#,*.swp,*.tmp,*_flymake.*,*_flymake,*.o,*.a,*.so,*.lo,*.zip,*.gz,*.bz2,*.xz,*.lzh,*.Z,*.tgz,*.min.js,*min.css,*_test.cc,build64_release/:
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibity seems to list all files to be tagged in gtags.files, e.g.:

```
ls *.cpp *.h > gtags.files
```