# IDE for debugging 'C source in linux

Tags: linux, ide, development-environment

Recently I am developing using 'C in Linux platforms, the tools like gcc are fast. But I wish it would be great to have an IDE like the VC++ IDE for windows.

Comment: Eh?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)
- [Anjuta](http://anjuta.sourceforge.net/)
- [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)
- Or [check](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+c+ide+linux) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579219/best-unix-linux-c-debuger-ide) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Answer (score 1):

There are Eclipse CDT (http://www.eclipse.org) and NetBeans C++ (http://www.netbeans.org), both great IDEs with pretty much same features as Visual Studio.
If you are starting developing for Linux and Windows, you might want to get a deep look into CMake (http://www.cmake.org) which will automate all your project files generation for all C/C++ IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice survey of the options on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments

If using Qt for development, the new Qt Creator IDE is quite nice, I find.

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the options the other posts have already mentioned, I will add [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/). Which is a nice front end for GDB.

I have to say that I have used Eclipse CDT, Netbeans and DDD. None of them come close to what you get with Visual Studio in my opinion. Eclipse and Netbeans, for C/C++ devel are slow and buggy. DDD is ok, but lacks a lot of the features you get with Microsoft tools.

Comment: Regarding debugging, what features are lacking in DDD?  I think that DDD is too often overlooked.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I like DDD. But when I used it, three or four years ago, whenever you had to go and do some thread inspecting, you had to use regular gdb commands instead of some option in the GUI. And I agree, DDD is too often overlooked. That's why I suggested it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Monodevelop can do C/C++ projects, and their latest release notes indicate that they have a [native code debugger](http://monodevelop.com/Release_notes_for_MonoDevelop_2.0_Beta_2).

If you are interested, watch the [Jupiter Broadcasting youtube channel](http://youtube.com/jupiterbroadcasting) because they are going to review Monodevelop 2.0 next week I believe.

Answer (score 0):

KDevelop has hooks for the GNU tool chain, as well as hooks for valgrind / cachegrind / etc. Its pretty light weight (responsive), rather intuitive and easy to get used to.

I normally just use KATE and open an inline terminal for stuff like valgrind / gdb. With debugging options on, its really easy to step through valgrind's output and fix things line by line in the code.

Both come with KDE, if you have KDE, you should already have these on your menu.

**Edit:**

[Here's a screenshot of KDevelop](http://echoreply.us/kdevelop.png) (from my desktop). That's a slightly old version, so I'm sure the interface offers more by now.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBlocks and Anjuta are pretty fair enough as pointed out by Brian Campbell