# Auto complete Text Editor for C

Tags: c

First post here and a new to C and programming in general. I do have a little HTML and CSS experience but I am in the process of working my way through C for Dummies.

I am trying to find a text editor that auto completes C code. Currently using SubEthaEdit which is the third text editor I have tried. How can I get it to auto complete?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, "text editors" do not support autocomplete themselves. Try an IDE (integrated development environment) for autocomplete functionality. There are many to choose from.

Are you using Windows? I've had very satisfactory experiences with [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html). Despite the name, it treats C every bit as well as it treats C++.

If you're on a Mac, check out [msiemeri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872186/auto-complete-text-editor-for-c/872214#872214). Xcode is free, but you need to sign up  for a free account at Apple. This is what I use on a Mac.

Comment: depends - Emacs or Vim support integration of ctags, e.g.

Comment: Notepad and edlin don't, but I can't think off-hand of any other text editor which doesn't support some form of autocompletion.

Comment: There's an auto-complete plugin for gedit, the manual for Smultron says F5 auto-completes, and the home page for Notepad++ has auto-complete as number 4 in the list of features.

Comment: Please note that Dev-C++ is no longer being developed and there are better IDEs..

Answer (score 4):

See [c-ide-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux) and many other similar SO questions.

Many IDEs mentioned are not limited to `Linux`, [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) works fine on `Windows`, and so does [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/features).

Comment: Code::Blocks is an amazing IDE, best I've come across.

Answer (score 4):

Since I assume, you're on a Mac (using SubEthaEdit), you might want to try [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/index.html), the "official" IDE on OSX.

It's more than a text editor, though.

Answer (score 2):

I use SciTE on linux for C.

There are a few reasons-

- I'm used to SciTE for editing Python, XML, JavaScript, and text config files on Windows and Linux.
- It's very configurable and reasonably fast
- I tend to use unit testing rather than debugging, so don't really care that much for debugger integration.

As with most good text editors, it has autocompletion and you can plug in your own commands. The set-up I use for C ( autocompletion, the standard APIs I use, project specific ctags, context sensitive help, build/test/run commands ) are detailed [here](http://www.tincancamera.com/blog/2009/01/scite-and-ctags.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) is a brilliant addon for the visual studio which has a very good autocomplete feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time, I'd recommend learning a serious text editor like Emacs or Vim. Both are great (I personally use Vim) and have tab completion with both default and customizable behavior (there are a ton of plugins online with extra functionality). By default, Ctrl-P in vim searches through the file and any linked files. For example, if you include stdio.h, then the tab completion engine will incorporate printf, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use gedit with plugins, it works great in Linux.

For installing additional plugins, enter the following command in the terminal:

```
apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim supports code completion with not much fussing about.

But also take, that "auto complete" is a very wide term. What exactly is it that you need ?
Intellisense - [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).
Omnicomplete - [Vim](http://www.vim.org).
.
.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider to try / learn Vim/Gvim look at [c.vim](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=213).

Answer (score 0):

We use Dev-C++ (you can use it for c) also Code::Blocks is good but these aren't only  text editors they are IDEs :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned SubEthaEdit, you must be using MacOS X.

Well, [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) is a good option for all platforms. I'd suggest you try it.

Answer (score 0):

As an IDE, I recommend Microsoft Visual Studio, the Express version is free.