# Vim - Auto-complete Java

Tags: java, vim, autocomplete

I find myself wanting to auto-complete things that I import in the .java file I'm editing. So for example I'm working on `Test.java`, and inside I have `import java.util.List;`. Can I auto-complete (Ctrl+n) the methods inside the List interface so that when I do something like `List l = new ArrayList(); l.<Ctrl+n>` the methods show up?

Comment: Best of luck – you’ll probably not get any useful answer though. For reference, also have a look at the question [Autocompletion in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1115876/1968).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be possible to use [**Eclim**](http://eclim.org/) to achieve this. I have no idea how usable this is, though.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=70822))</sub>

Comment: Eclim is also the one I found but it requires the entire Eclipse stuff. I wish there was a more standalone vim "plugin" but I guess eclim is really the only thing there is.

Answer (score 5):

The [javacomplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1785) omnicompletion script seems to provide an extensive feature list. I don't know if it works with what you're asking but it does not need eclim.

There's also the [Vim JDE script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1213) but it needs vim built with ruby support.

Comment: I've used the javacomplete script and it works very well. It comes with a Reflection class that it uses to get completions. However, I've since switched to using eclim. (I use eclipse to debug, so I might as well use it for completions too.)