# Vim auto-completion for C++'s #include clause

Tags: c++, c, vim

I just installed omnicomplete plugin, does it support header auto completion?

When I typed `#include <`, is it possible to provide a list of header files to complete?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have c.vim (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213)?

Comment: What omni-completion plugin did you install?

Comment: @ib , app-vim/omnicppcomplete-0.41

Comment: @yasouser , is that script mandatory for that plugin ?

Comment: If you are asking whether c.vim is mandatory for omnicomplete.cim, then no. But c.vim has lots of feature you usually find in a c/c++ IDE.

Comment: Maybe it will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/1115876/1035174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the *vim autocomplete* feature, which was introduced in vim7.

Just type in first few characters and press `Ctrl->P(for backward search)` or `Ctrl->N(for forward search)`, vim lists down all options available or completes it.

And Yes it works even for header files.

To make this work you should install [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) 
In `usr/include` add:

```
ctags -f ~/.vim/stdtags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .
```

Add this to your `.vimrc`

```
    set nocp
    filetype plugin on
    map <C-L> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR><CR>

    set tags=~/.vim/stdtags,tags,.tags,../tags

    autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
```

Comment: Do you have a plug-in for that ? I have Vim 7.3 under Ubuntu, no special plugin, and when I type `#include <vec` and `ctrl+N` it doesn't get autocompleted to `vector`.

Comment: i think ^P ^N only search for strings already present in the file , i'm on 7.3.219 in Gentoo

Comment: @warl0ck. Actually `<C-n>` will search all the open buffers and then some (f.ex. included files) for keywords. You can control its scope by settings.

Comment: @progo , i think i understood how vim works , if i type in #include < , with no extra strings , it won't complete for all the headers , but for everything , am i right on this part ?

Comment: @warl0ck, sure thing. Everything it sees as a keyword. But it won't limit its search to the current buffer (there's `<C-x><C-n>` for that).