# learning c++ on linux mint ( for .net developer )

Tags: c++, linux

My goal is to hop on to C++ programming language by doing a homework project on linux mint and learn some linux & c++ at the same time.

I intend to write a small desktop application to show current network traffic ( like DU meter in windows). I have following questions:

1. I noticed in mint there is an application called 'System Monitor' which also shows network history with info and graph like current download/upload of data and speed. Is it a good idea to get started by looking at the code for this ? how can I find the code for same in mint and dig into it ? pls help with some steps here if possible.
2. what tools do I need here for writing c++ application for/in linux mint ?
3. Which GUI library to use ( like in c# winforms , it offers user controls as part of GDI lib) on linux mint what do we have that offers user controls like window/button/panel/etc ?
4. Links to beginner level tutorials will be helpful.
5. Hoping NOT to re-invent the wheel completely here. Would love to re-use some lib that do the network traffic part, ideas ?

PS: i know this post reads 'wanna be' - I am really excited to kickstart with some c++.  Will rephrase this post with more precise questions.Hunting in the dark at this point being a c# developer totally spoiled by windows.

Thanks in Advance!!! for tips on this...

Comment: I appologize for being years late, but for fairly in-depth network stats in C++, you should check out QPcap.  QPcap Provides a QT style C++ API for libpcap, and fits right in with a QT application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mint distribution is based on Ubuntu/Debian, so I assume that my Ubuntu approach also works on mint.

**First**

you need some tools, libraries and headers:

```
# install the standard toolchain (g++, make, etc.)
sudo aptitude install build-essential

# install the build dependencies for a desktop based networking tool
sudo aptitude  build-dep gnome-nettool
```

**Optionally**

because you mentioned the system-monitor - it might be helpful to build the gnome-system-monitor from source:

```
# install the build dependencies for gnome-system-monitor
sudo aptitude  build-dep gnome-system-monitor

# get the sources for the gnome-system-monitor
mkdir example
cd example
apt-get source gnome-system-monitor

# build the gnome-system-monitor
# note: you might have a different version. But I'm sure you get the idea ;-)
cd  gnome-system-monitor-2.28.0
sh configure
make
```

**Finally**

you need something to develop and debug. A lot of unix developers recommend emacs or vi(m). But my personal opinion is that you should start with a "modern" GUI based IDE.

here's a collection of some commonly used IDEs:

- Eclipse with CDT
- NetBeans
- Code::Blocks
- Anjuta (was this used to develop the gnome-system-monitor ?)
- CodeLite (which is my personal favorite)

see also: discussion on SOF regarding "the best" [C++ IDE for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux/1775460#1775460)

Answer (score 4):

People usually use text editors like (g)Vim or emacs to write C++ applications. If you've never seen them before they may be a bit overwhelming. You can also use IDEs like Geany, Anjuta, QtCreator, Eclipse...

I think the default desktop environment in Mint is [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/) which uses the GTK library. You could use GTK for your application. It is written in C but there is a c++ interface for it, [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/), and a tutorial for it on the projects site.

There is also [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), which is the base of the K Desktop Environment or [KDE](http://www.kde.org/). It is a very large library and has a pretty good IDE written in it, for it, QtCreator.

Finally, you should search stackoverflow because most of your questions have already been answered.

Comment: You should definitely learn emacs before you do anything else related to programming in Linux. Trust me, its a very worthwhile investment.

Comment: @nagnatron - "default desktop environment in Mint is GNOME" - "Qt is based on KDE" - does it conflict with defalut env being GNOME ?

Comment: @dotnetcoder: Qt is not based on KDE, but the other way around. KDE is made with Qt. They don't conflict. Qt apps in GNOME just look a bit different from native GTK apps.

Comment: @miloshadzic: This is no longer the case, though.

Comment: @phresnel I don't actually program in C++ much any more so tell you what: You suggest what I should edit and I'll update my answer and credit you.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to you "what tools do I need", you should at a minimum install `g++`, the standard C++ compiler on a GNU/Linux system.

Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu (which is in turn based on Debian), so for a binary like `gnome-system-monitor`, the command

```
apt-get source $(dpkg -S $(which gnome-system-monitor) | cut -d: -f1)
```

will download and unpack the source package for it in the current directory. Note that it probably depends on a number of libraries, that can be found in different packages. You can see what these are with `apt-cache show package_name`, and libraries often have associated development packages named with `-dev` that contain the associated headers and statically-linked archives. You can find the dev package names by  searching using `apt-cache search foo`, where foo is the base name of the library package you're interested in.