# Linux app using C++ and visual studio

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I want to write an app in visual studio that will work in linux.  It's main function will be to monitor multiple linux systems and provide health and status to the GUI... I.e disk usage, bad drives, network throughput, mysql reads/inserts, ect... Can I cross compile with visual studio 2010?

Should I even bother using visual studio?  Or should I bail and use Java or C++ on linux?

---

Thanks for the help guys, looks like the inevitable is true!  I was just looking at netbeans, so I guess I will use that.  I don't normally write for Linux, so I will just have to plow through it :)

Thanks

Comment: it sounds like the program you're writing is very similar to nagios, which is open source and runs on linux and windows: http://www.nagios.org/

Answer (score 4):

If you like the VS IDE, you can certainly use it to write code that's portable to Linux, though actually compiling the code for Linux will be separate. In theory, you *could* probably configure VS to compile your code with gcc as a post-build step, for example, but it would probably be more work than it was worth.

At least IMO, if you're trying write code that's portable to Windows and Linux (e.g., using Qt for its UI), and you're comfortable with VS, it's *probably* worth using VS to do most of the work. If you prefer Linux tools *or* you're writing the code exclusively for Linux, then you're probably better off using Linux tools throughout.

Answer (score 2):

No; Microsoft Visual Studio does not contain a cross compiler for Linux. Nothing says you cannot use the C++ you build in Visual Studio on Linux machines though; you would just need to compile to code there.

Answer (score 2):

As Visual Studio does neither run on Linux natively nor can it produce native Linux code, I would recommend you use the target platform's native toolchain to build your software.

If your goal is to create a *portable* application that runs on both Windows and Linux, starting one Windows with Visual Studio and recompiling the code on the Linux system on a regular basis is probably a pretty decent approach.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use Visual Studio to develop, but you can't create the Linux executable with it - for that you need to use the gcc compiler under Linux. You'll find a few differences between the compilers that will give you some grief, and unfortunately a lot of those differences will be in the areas you're targeting - O/S services. It's a judgement call which would be easier but in your case I'd bite the bullet and use the Linux tools exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Bail.

Maybe look into monodevelop which is much less nice than Visual Studio.
Netbeans and/or Eclipse for linux are nice though.

Answer (score 1):

Bail, Visual Studio is definitively not the best tool for this particular job.

If you want to code C++ for GNU/Linux, there are a lot of good IDEs in there: Eclipse, NetBeans, KDevelop, Codeblocks...

Also, check the answers on this question: [C++ IDE for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux), I think you'll find some useful stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I've used VS to write code that was supposed to work on Windows and *nix. I'd figure out a configuration method for *nix and as you go before every major commit try compiling the code with gcc. Visual Studio's Intellisense and VC++ debugger murder Eclipse+CDT+gdb in every way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly partial to [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/developer-tools) for my x-platform C++ tasks.