# Vim code completion

Tags: c++, vim, code-completion

Is it possible to make Vim complete the code for you, like in any other IDE (not just word searching, but members of classes, methods etc.)?

What are the best options / plugins available?

Comment: http://design.liberta.co.za/articles/code-completion-intellisense-for-cpp-in-vim-with-omnicppcomplete/

Answer (score -6, accepted):

It's possible, but most people don't.

vim is a fairly generic editor, that said, it does contain some "code completion" features such as word completion, etcetera, but nothing like the likes of, say, Delphi's IDE.

Such a system could be added by scripting vim - vim can directly run several scripting languages that make this easy, or you could send the file through an external script.

Comment: Scripting is definitely NOT the way to go.

Comment: Martin: How do you think such a feature would be implemented?

Comment: you should use @name notation somewhere in your comment if you want people to get notified about your replies to their comments. Very nice feature.

Comment: @Martin: How do you think such a feature would be implemented?

Comment: @Martin: Ah! A script?  That said, I think ctags-based completions fall massively short compared with commercial IDE's.  Commercial IDE's provide context-sensitive completion. Also, that link you provided mentions that it doesn't work with boost. That's a pretty massive drawback for something claiming to support C++.

Comment: I think the number of votes you got reflects the quality of your answer. Enough  said.

Answer (score 12):

[Clang Complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) lets you use Clang for accurate auto-completion of C and C++

Answer (score 11):

I believe that following this list of links you will be able to leave any IDE and become a faithful user of vim, see some plugins that help you with IDE resources...

- snipMate plugin [faster code complete skels](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)
- video showing snipmate [on vimeo](http://vimeo.com/3535418)
- article about sparkup html codding [to understand this resource](http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2010/03/04/write-html-faster-with-sparkup-vim-and-textmate/)
- video showing sparkup html complete [to see this in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jw3jipcenKc)
- Auto complete popup plugin [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879)
- [Advanced undo resource](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/)
- some interesting videos on advanced usage of vim [on vimeo](http://vimeo.com/user1690209/videos)
- more free videos [at vimcasts.org](http://vimcasts.org/)
- amazing article about vim [in this link](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/)
- vim for php programmers (useful not only for php programmers) [here](http://zmievski.org/2007/02/vim-for-php-programmers-slides-and-resources)

Answer (score 7):

This is a little out dated. A rising star in Vim code completion is the "YouCompleteMe" plugin. Check it out [here](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/).

Answer (score 6):

Omni completion is definitely the way to go. Instantiate it in insert mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

I use it in conjunction with [SuperTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643) as well to allow for tab completion similar to bash shell.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use it myself but I have heard of Omni complete:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion

The [Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/) contains a couple of things that may be of use for auto completion of words.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out [Dictionary completions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Dictionary_completions), get dictionary for you language. Simple ways

if you are programming in c++, there are ctag and cscope and with [OmniCppComplete](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion) plugin.

Hope it will help