# C++/Assembly IDE on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, ide

What I'm looking for is an IDE that will run on Linux, that has support for C++ and x86 assembly syntax highlighting. I've already tried Code::Blocks, but that won't let me run the program as I need to, so that didn't work well.

My needs:

- Able to compile programs by issuing a "make all" in a certain directory
- Able to run programs by issuing a custom command instead of running a certain executable
- Graphical (not vim/emacs/etc) and will run in GNOME/Fedora 14

What would be very helpful:

- Git integration
- Autoversioning (like Code::Blocks does)

Eclipse doesn't work for me, as it no matter what I set it tries to do an auto-build/error check of the entire program, using the wrong toolchain, and errors out everything, even if I disable CDT.

Assembly syntax highlighting is not a *requirement* but would be useful. It does, however, have to have C++ syntax highlighting.

EDIT: By "Graphical" I mean that I already tried vim/emacs some time ago, and found them too challenging to learn how to use in a short amount of time without loosing my sanity.

EDIT 2: The given editor should also store project files in just one file, as I don't want to have to "git add" a whole new directory each time the editor silently adds some file there.

Comment: Thanks for the netbeans tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: I tried netbeans, however it doesn't seem to have a setting to disable the auto-generation of a makefile, and it seems intent on always running that makefile it generates.

Comment: I count more than half a dozen similar questions in the "related sidebar" goinb back to sequence number 2756. It's been done to death.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ IDE for Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Vim

Be sure to look at

- [C++ Omni Completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1608)
- ctags and [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273)

  - I use `ctags --exclude=packagedir -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .`
- [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net) ([here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cscope) and [here](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html))

Simply the best editor and will work anywhere - including in your remote terminal under screen :)

#### Eclipse CDT

Eclipse can import existing makefile projects and will not clobber the makefile :)
Eclipses intellisense is nice

I use Eclipse HELIOS on linux. It supports

- profiling,
- memchecking with valgrind
- GDB debugging, remote debugging
- call graph visualization, comprehensive symbol XRef (the usual eclipse shortcuts apply), simple refactorings
- coverage GCov
- oprofile
- ...

It should be portable so I expect most of this to work on windows.

Comment: I guess I'll try Eclipse again, to see if it will work better than last time I tried it, however the IDE I found called Geany does all of what I need except auto-versioning, which I can easily write a script for.

Answer (score 5):

What do you think about KDevelop?

Comment: In the question I specified that it had to run under GNOME, and using KDevelop would mean installing all of the KDE libraries, which last time I checked was about 400mb.

Comment: So short on disk space? I have written a syntax highlighting for x86_64 and kdevelop, since then it works very well ;-)

Comment: I LOVE it for ASM! it's just like Kate, only better!

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to go the commercial route there is **SlickEdit**, which works on multiple platforms and with multiple languages (including the two you have mentioned).

http://www.slickedit.com/products/slickedit/

Comment: This looks like a good program, but I'm not currently willing to spend money on an editor.

Answer (score 2):

Today, the best IDE for assembler on LINUX is SASM. [Official site of SASM](https://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think **emacs** is the best multi-language editor.

Comment: Dude, did you read the question?

Comment: Emacs match all the needs, and of course it is graphical. But do you have an idea of what emacs is, dude?

Comment: By "graphical" I meant that you can do everything using either keyboard shortcuts or graphical menus, not like emacs/gemacs/etc where it's, last time I checked, mostly keyboard shortcuts that have a steep learning curve.

Comment: Emacs can compile programs using the makefile that you supply, using a custom compile command.  Emacs can help you run the program the way you want instead of simply invoking the binary you build.  Emacs has a decent git integration where you can do all version control operations from within Emacs.  Emacs has a decent syntax highlighting facility.  Emacs has keybindings for many of its commands (which is what you want, inferring from "can do everything using either keyboard shortcuts or graphical menus").  What do you find Emacs wanting?

Comment: @Eli emacs allows you use just graphical menus and keyboard shortcuts. (But if you start using it, a day you will go beyond)