# is there light linux c++ IDE+Visual debugger like eclipse cdt?

Tags: c++, linux, ide, debugging

its so heavy when i use it with xming /xserver is there something better but with the same great function eclipse have for linux c++ development / visual debugging

Comment: Emacs? It's fantastic (only problem is that it's very non-visual and keyboard-oriented, I understand if that's not your thing).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ IDE for Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice UI for debugger: [Nemiver](http://projects.gnome.org/nemiver/)

Light C++ IDE: [Geany](http://www.geany.org/)

Comment: Geany is great. Simple but has almost everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [KDevelop](http://kdevelop.org/).
But I would not call it light. That is a full blown IDE.

Comment: I would argue any IDE suite similar to Eclipse or Visual Studio isn't "light".  The simple reason these tools are used is because provide a way to do those time consuming tasks quickly ( auto-adjust the indention of code for example ).

Comment: I agree, but the OP already used light in the context of the CDT. From my point of view KDevelop is lighter than the CDT but I don't want to start a flame war.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes check [KDbg](http://www.kdbg.org/).

> KDbg is a graphical user interface to gdb, the GNU debugger. It provides an intuitive interface for setting breakpoints, inspecting variables, and stepping through code.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best programming environment for C++ is [CodeBlocks](http://codeblocks.org/). It even provides a GUI editor for wxWidgets, if your application is visual.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not impossible to just use eclipse CDT on windows

http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=eclipse+windows+cdt&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

I suggest

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmax.berger.name%2Fhowto%2Fcdt%2F&ei=fbW-Td7BPND1sga5_5yLBg&usg=AFQjCNGCLwoeu505z0LrhjnygeCV39mM5w&sig2=3hEyj1kIDjsYahUYAc5VuA

and

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHAQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.wxwidgets.org%2FEclipse%2C_CDT_%2526_MingW_Setup_Guide&ei=fbW-Td7BPND1sga5_5yLBg&usg=AFQjCNEGBZglyfqt-Cc_OVMtoMilvTIKNQ&sig2=-_01zFPbdfQd0tf2GFNgjg