# IDE on Linux with Intellisense

Tags: linux, ide

until now i write c++ code on windows and microsoft visual c++ 2010 but there`s a project that i must do it on Linux , in Microsoft visual c++ 2010 there was a feature named code completion or intellisense that was available with Ctrl + Space , it shows you a list of suggested function or other components with this name or similar to it, but i could not find any feature like this on IDEs on linux. could any body suggest me an IDE to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have good experiences with the C/C++ Plugin in Netbeans. Eclipse also have C/C++ Plugins but many Visual Studio Users don't like Eclipse and its handling.

Comment: what about Netbeans ? does intellisence of netbeans work on linux?

Comment: Yes it does. I used the IDE in a rather obscure configuration: Netbeans on a Windows Host and compiler and source code inside a VirtualBox VM connected through a shared folder and it worked. Netbeans contains a build in plugin portal which contains the C/C++ Plugin. Just download it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) or [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) is probably the most similar ones to Visual Studio in this regard. See more info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Comment: @Mohsen Nakhjavvani I use both every day.