# Is there a free C++ IDE for Linux with these features?

Tags: c++, linux, ide, cgal

1. List all methods in a class, preferably with options to enable/disable methods from superclasses.
2. Option for a "go to source" once you select a variable.

I'm trying to use [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) and I can't make sense of a whole lot from the documentation or the compiler errors, despite using as many flags as possible in GCC, so I downloaded the source code to take a look at it to try to see if I can find the methods I need. These two options would make things a lot easier.

When I used netbeans for Java it had both options, so maybe it'd have for C++ as well? Or am I expecting too much out of it? Or maybe another IDE would work better? I have no idea. Normally I just use gedit with make.

Comment: Have you tried KDevelop?

Comment: Check out KDevelop.  *EDIT*: I love you, Frank.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux (which does not require free however) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579219/best-unix-linux-c-debuger-ide (which points to even more similar questions)

Comment: I have a colleague who uses KDevelop on KDE 3.5 or 3.x, and he's always complaining about it so I didn't think it was a good IDE. I've never used it though.

Comment: I'm too lazy to post a KDevelop answer, but I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Code Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org) or [Code Lite](http://www.codelite.org).

Answer (score 1):

Every seems too lazy to post the [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) answer, so here it is.

Answer (score 0):

None as good as Visual Studio. Options you may try: Eclipse with CDT, Anjuta, KDevelop, vim+ctags.

Comment: Even better: vim+clang_complete.

Comment: vim will provide you with the most incredible startup time unlike all the other overloaded graphical programs ;)

Comment: You could also look at kate+ctags ...

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Eclipse with CDT plugin. I'm not sure it has all the features you ask for but you get most of Eclipse's power, for free, in c++

Answer (score 0):

I personally dislike Eclipse with the CDT plugin. I would either use QtCreator or Netbeans. Both of these have the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans and Eclipse both have poor C++ support, IMO. QtCreator is my personal favorite for Linux IDEs. (Well, after emacs ;) )

Comment: Just curious, I've never used QtCreator before ... does it work well with non-Qt objects (i.e., like STL, Boost, etc.), or is it mainly oriented towards development within the bounds of Qt?

Comment: @Jason I haven't had any problems with it and I'm using boost and STL.

Comment: I'm assuming the compiler is still gcc?

Comment: @Jason Whatever compiler you want to use, AFAIK. I'm using it with icc, but have also used it with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), Netbeans or Eclipse will do the job.

I would go for Codeblocks. It supports the features that you need and it is also extensible via plugins.