# Find Command that returns line number of the string

Tags: linux

I have a bunch of files organized into directories..All these are text files (c/c++). I am trying to understand this code and i need to look at the declarations of many variables..How can i use find command to get the exact location( File Name with line number(s) ) using Find command in ubuntu linux?? Or is there any graphical tool for doing the same?

Comment: This feature should be provided by your IDE. See [C++ IDE for Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Comment: Is there any graphical tool to do the same???

Comment: The second answer from [the question I've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux) mentions:  Code::Blocks, Eclipse CDT. [Search linux ide on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D+ide).

Answer (score 22):

You can do this with grep. `grep -n 'search-term' *.c` will give you the filename and line number where the term appears.

Comment: This will fail if there are sub directories ;-)

Comment: You can use `grep -nr ...` to search recursively inside sub-directories.

Answer (score 8):

```
find . -name *.c -exec grep -Hn "your search term here" {} \;
```

If you really want to use `find`.

*EDIT*

**explanation**

`find . -name *.c` - find files in current dir and below where name is like *.c

`-exec` - execute command that follows

`grep -Hn` - grep and print results with file name and line number of match

`{} \;` - {} marks where the name of each file found will be substituted and the backslash-
semicolon marks the end of the command to execute.