# IDE for C/C++ programming in Linux

Tags: linux, ide

Which IDE is best for coding in C/C++ in Linux which offers the following:

1. debugging
2. code completion
3. tooltips / documentation (function definitions)

Also if the IDE can be used in general for Python and Perl coding it would be the best choice available.

Comment: Any true IDE will fit all 3 points. As such, this is a very generic recommendation question and not a good fit for SO. (OT: NetBeans is a good choice)

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: That's the problem. There are a lot of IDEs that don't do that and few that do. He's asking for one that does.

Comment: @Linux all IDEs do debugging and code completion (point 2 and point 3 are the same). IDE stands for *integrated* development environment.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: Not all of them do *good* code completion. Many will only offer help after your done typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal favorite is KDevelop. I've never used its debugger (I use straight `gdb`) but its code completion and documentation viewers are excellent. One of the best you'll every find. Also, it's not written in Java but C or C++, so it runs faster on worse systems.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). It has good support for C/C++ via [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/). It has all the features that you are requesting. It has also support for python via a plugin called [pydev](http://pydev.org/). For perl you have [epic](http://www.epic-ide.org/).

Moreover, there are many more plugins available. Just a brief list:

1. SVN integration
2. Support for many linux tools (autotools, valgrind, gcov, gprof, etc.)
3. Application lifecycle (Mylyn)

Feel free to check answers for a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux) in stackoverflow too.

And wikipedia always comes handy. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments) you have a comparison of many IDEs, grouped by programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) for C++ development. It is tightly coupled to programming using the `Qt` toolkit (which I occasionally require), but works well for more "generic" programs. I particularly like its great support for `CMake`. Of course `qmake` is supported as well. In addition to this the `QtCreator` is *platform-independent* and has built-in support for several version control systems, including `SVN` and `git`. Last, but not least, its debugging capabilities are great (although I sometimes prefer using `gdb` manually).

Edit: To clarify: `QtCreator` neither supports Python nor Perl. It is meant for C/C++ programming only. For Perl, I personally like the [vim editor](http://www.vim.org/) best (using nothing but the normal syntax highlighting; I am a bit of a purist there). For Python, I cannot recommend anything and hope my fellow stackoverflowers will step in :)