# Debugger with GUI for C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Currently I am doing C++ Development on Windows and Mac using Visual Studio and XCode respectively and planning to start on Linux too.

I know just a little about Linux, gcc/g++, gdb, Makefile.

Can one who works on large GUI development, how they debug it, as using gdb command-line tool for debugging will be difficult, as I have been in comfort of visual studio / xcode(front-end) debugger?

I see only Makefile for project on linux, is eclipse ide make project on basis of makefile?

Thanks

Comment: You could run `make`, `gdb`, some shell from inside `emacs`. Learning the Linux (i.e. command line) way of doing thing is worth the effort....

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Thanks a lot for your reply! Can you please point at some tutorial{video if possible} how to set up vim for c++ development or some guideline of debugging and managing c++ project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux

Comment: I was talking of `emacs` not `vi`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple to work on project with existing makefile in Eclipse.

Just go to File -> Import -> C/C++ -> Existing code as Makefile project.

This will let you build your project from IDE. To debug it just go to Run -> Debug. If default launch generated this way is not ok for you, you can customized Launch configuration in Run ->  Debug configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse will do all of that stuff for you, including creating your makefile.  Before you compile for the first time, just press ctrl+B and it will build your project for you.

All of your library linking can be done by clicking on the "project" menu, then under C/C++build, click "settings". There should be a setting on there somewhere that says "libraries", which is listed under GCC/C++ linker.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what if I have some library and I want to create project for it, using the Makrfile provided by the library.

Comment: All of your library linking can be done by clicking on the "project" menu, then under C/C++build, click "settings". There should be a setting on there somewhere that says "libraries", which I think is under GCC/C++ linker. I cant remember where exactly, but you can specify your provided makefile in this menu also.

Comment: I know Vim, I think that will do. After configuring the makefile, What need to be done to create something corresponding  libName.vcporject for eclipse. Sorry, If my question bother you, as currently I am thinking everything I do on windows platform... But at the same time I do understand thing will be very differently in Linux World.

Comment: after creating the makefile, you can use the "make" command from your terminal. just type the word make followed by your target file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several IDE for linux as

- [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)
- [Codelite](http://codelite.org/)

which may also use custom makefile.

Comment: How to use the Makefile provided by  the library or some open source to create project using these IDEs?

Comment: There is a option in project settings.

Comment: Can you specify where, and the steps?