# Jump to the right C++ STL documentation page in QtCreator after F1?

Tags: c++, qt, stl, documentation, qt-creator

QtCreator comes with cool Qt-related documentation and functionality: when you select a Qt class and press F1, it opens a sidebar with that class specific documentation page.

Now, QtCreator lets me install C++ documentation (found here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Creator_Documentation_Gallery - I've tried the en.cppreference.com version). However, selecting an STL class and pressing F1 only opens the default, generic page listine, sort of "Home" of the documentation.

Is it possible to have a mimic functionality for C++ STL docs to the one of Qt docs?

Also, I've checked it in QtCreator 2.4 running on Ubuntu 12.04. Is it maybe fixed in newer versions?

Comment: Anyway, why do you use 2 years old version? There is 3.1 just came out.

Comment: It's the one in Ubuntu's PPA. I've had some trouble running 3.1 (GLX related). I'm asking sort of while looking around for "the" C++ IDE on Linux for me.

Comment: Offtopic: You know, I tried these `qch` files in my QtCreator 3.1 and its crashes when evoking help. So terrible. If you are searching for IDE for linux, take a look here: [C++ IDE for Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux). **Warning! Opinion-based offtopic follows!** KDevelop, Eclipse CDT and QtCreator are very best, but still they are very primitive in terms of productivity if we compare 'em to Visual Studio + Visual Assist. With help of virtual machines, git/hg and some plugin/script magic it's not impossible to set up cross-platform development in MSVC nowadays

Comment: @Drop Offtopic: Sorry I thought I had replied. MSVC for Linux... tried with some scripting - tedious and difficult to maintain, tried Visual GDB - not fully working. Thanks for the advice though, I'll try KDevelop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you're still looking for an answer to this (or for anyone else finding this posting), there is a working solution now. In the [**official documentation gallery**](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Creator_Documentation_Gallery) there is a download link labelled **STL documentation**. That version will provide correctly working context sensitive look-up. There are a few things where that seems to fail though (like std::unique_ptr), but for most things I tested it works just fine. Some things find a technically correct but not helpful entry though. As an example, std::fill(...) will link to the correct entry in "std Namespace Reference" (which is just a line of the definition, and not linked to anything useful either) but not the description on the "Mutating" page (which is the first suggestion when searching for 'fill' via the index).

Please ignore the two links that are still at the top of that page though, those either completely lock-up the help system (`docs.google.com`) or just don't provide context sensitive help (`en.cppreference.com`).

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded the documentation via https://en.cppreference.com/w/File:qch_book_20181028.zip link and in `qt-creator` I add the new document using tools->option->Help->Documentation Add button :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, cppreference docs don't support navigation with F1.

Comment: do you have any knowledge whether this would be difficult to implement? or is there any other cpp documentation with this?

Comment: Doxygen can generate F1 compilant docs with appropriate doxygen config file; this method suitable for 3rd-party libraries like OGRE. As far as I know, it's not suitable for C++ standard library.