# Is there an equivalent of -I (capital I) for object files in g++?

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have several object files coming from different directories (they are stored near the corresponding source that generated them). Is there a way that given this directory structure

Root

```
main.o
```

Root/Some_long_path

```
object_1.o
object_2.o
```

I could run a command like this

```
g++ -Wall main.o -ISome_long_path object_1.o object_2.o -o app
```

So that I don't have to put the full path in front of every object file. What would go instead of the -I command?

I am using gcc version 4.8.3 (from Cygwin installation).

Comment: There is `-L` option for searching libraries (`lib*.so` and `lib*.a` in unix terms), and seems there is no gcc option for object files (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options). You can use make + makefiles to put right path automatically.

Comment: You shouldn't need to put a full path, use a relative path.

Comment: @osgx Thanks, I'm going to have to spend some time today learning how to write/use makefiles. Some of my code is used in several applications, e.g. input validation modules, I feel this should be treated like a library - how would I create a library file?

Comment: @Barmar I meant is there a way to avoid writing out the full relative path each time. All the paths are relative (Root is the base folder of my application, not my system)

Comment: You could put the long path prefix in a variable and use `$dir/object_1.o`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I've just done that and it works great :) Going to start using a makefile now though, I just hadn't come across them before

Comment: In the makefile you can use `vpath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So that I don't have to put the full path in front of every object file. What would go instead of the `-I` command?

There is no gcc option like `-I` to add some directory to the object "search path", and there is no search path for objects. But there is search path for libraries (usually named `lib*.a` for static libraries and `lib*.so` for shared libraries in Unix world).

Directory-Options manual of gcc lists only `-I` option for include paths and `-L` option for library paths. There is no object path:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

And Link-Options manual of gcc mention only `-L` option (near `-l` description):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options

What can you use:

- shell variables or environment variables (in bash: `OBJ_DIR=./path/to/dir` then `g++ ... $OBJ_DIR/obj1.o $OBJ_DIR/obj2.o`)
- Packing several objects from single directory to single [static library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) `libSome_Long_Component_Name.a` (this type of library is just like the archive of  several `*.o` object files and some extra info made with `ar rcs`); then you can use `g++ ... -Ldir/ -lSome_Long_Component_Name`
- `Makefile`s and some variant of make utility (gnu make for linux and cygwin, nmake for windows's MSVC; you can start from gnu make manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile then "2.4 Variables Make Makefiles Simpler" then "4.3 Types of Prerequisites" - with example of `addprefix` command to ask make find objects in some objdir. There is also [VPATH special variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) which instructs make to search sources and objects in several directories; but all objects in project should have different names).
- Some IDE with support of Unix projects ([Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org), [list1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux), [list2](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Devtools/ides.html), [wikilist of C/C++ IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B)?); they usually manage all sources of you project and are able to generate Makefiles for project.
- Some more modern build system, not the make: like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), [SCons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCons) (or  qmake if you use Qt).

Comment: Thanks a lot - incredibly detailed answer! I've got a makefile now, I'll take a look at that `addprefix` command later today and also combining sections of my project into libraries :)