# Is there a Linux C IDE that supports intellisense for C library function?

Tags: c, linux, ide, intellisense

I am new to Linux C programming. And I am used to Visual Studio intellisense which can prompt function name and parameter list after I typing a few letters. Is there C IDE that can do similar things for `library functions`? Suppose I have composed the include paths properly.

I tried `KDevelop`. But it failed to identify the `printf` and similar functions.
(And some UI bugs also - the `Solve` button I guess).

[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You should only ask if you are lost. This is not for parallel-processing.

Answer (score 1):

[Use NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/index.html). It supports c, c++ and can prompt library functions. Install, and press CTRL+SPACE to list library functions, class, etc.

also:
[C++ IDE for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Besides everything.. why you don't just type:

```
$: vim
```

in terminal to get best editor? ; )

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)? It's powerful cross-platform IDE. It's [free](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/) for students.