# how to make compiling OpenGL C++ program "easier"?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using linux mint 17.2 and have downloaded everything necessary to program in OpenGL.

When I download test program and save it in text editor as (for example)  test.cpp I need to do this command in terminal to compile it:

```
g++ test.cpp -o proba  -lglut -lGL
```

I wanna skip this -lglut and -lGL part so it is automatically included. How is it possible ? Can it be done in some IDE like CODEBLOCKS maybe ?

Comment: [IDEs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux) and even text editors often provide functionality to build, run and debug app in one click or key press

Comment: Also, you can use some build system: make and cmake are probably the most popular

Comment: Scripts/batch files would work too, but make is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Makefile that looks like this:

```
all:
        g++ test.cpp -o proba  -lglut -lGL
```

Then simply type `make` and it will compile your program. Note: indent with a TAB in the makefile.

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)