# Navigate using function call stack in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, gnu, tui

In Visual Studio, if you click on an entry in the call stack, that opens editor and shows you the source code for that function. Is something similar possible in gdb? I use tui (text user interface) in gdb. Is it possible to make tui show source code for a given entry in backtrace?

If not, then how do you make use of information in backtrace? Do you manually open the files and navigate to correct line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you stopped with `gdb` (in any mode) in breakpoint and can see backtrace with `backtrace` or `where` commands, use `up` and `down` commands to focus on different functions (frames) of backtrace.

You may use `up 2` to go two frames upper. `list` command will show you source lines around current frame.

I think, tui will change current displayed function/registers after `up`/`down` commands; and there can be no point-and-click backtrace in tui (is there any support of mouse in tui?). Only documented windows of tui are 
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html

> source, assembly, and command windows.

There are keys to change current frame in TUI, but not in the normal TUI mode (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html), so you can use text commands of gdb.

There is also "TUI Single Key Mode", activated by `Ctrl-x s`, and there are up/down commands in this mode: `u`/`d` and `w` to get backtrace. The mode is documented at https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Single-Key-Mode.html#TUI-Single-Key-Mode:

> 25.3 TUI Single Key Mode
>
> ```
>  w    where
>  u    up
>  d    down
>  r    run
>  s    step
>  n    next
>  c    continue
>  f    finish
>  q    exit the SingleKey mode.
>  v    info locals
> ```
>
> Other keys temporarily switch to the gdb command prompt. The key that was pressed is inserted in the editing buffer so that it is possible to type most gdb commands without interaction with the TUI SingleKey mode. Once the command is entered the TUI SingleKey mode is restored. The only way to permanently leave this mode is by typing `q` or `C-x s`.

You may also try some debugger with GUI ([gnu `ddd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Display_Debugger) or [KDbg](http://www.kdbg.org/)), or any other gdb wrapper builtin in most Linux IDEs ([list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux), [wiki list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B): Eclipse, Netbeans, CLion, KDevelop, Code::Blocks, CodeLite, ...). They all are more modern and convenient for debugging.

Comment: `up` and `down` worked in tui also. Awesome!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @typetraitor, how can I start tui mode of gdb?

Comment: Just do `Ctrl+x+a`

Comment: @typetraitor, there are also single key navigation command with up and down in tui - check https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Single-Key-Mode.html#TUI-Single-Key-Mode "Type C-x s to switch into this mode,... u up, d down, q quit mode". I see no source code search in TUI, it is debugger, not source code navigator.

Comment: (gdb) w                                                                                                        Missing arguments.

Answer (score 9):

To add to osgx's answer, you can also use e.g. `frame 7` to go to the frame labeled #7 in the `backtrace` instead of just using `up`/`down`.

Comment: (gdb) w                                                                                                        `Missing arguments. `

Comment: @CSQGB Did you mean to comment that on the other answer?