# Show calling function of current function in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm stopped at a breakpoint in a function in gdb:

```
(gdb) frame
#0  generateBlocks (coinbaseScript=std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 0) 0x7fffc8000e80, nGenerate=1, nMaxTries=1000000, keepScript=false) at rpc/mining.cpp:117
117         unsigned int nExtraNonce = 0;
(gdb)
```

Is there a way to find out where this function was called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the callstack/backtrace. For that, just use the `backtrace`/`bt` or `where` command. [More detail, e.g., here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38448493/2064761).